# Bricked iMac, Overwrote the boot loader. Any options?

Tags: macos, mac, boot, bootloader

I was installing linux on my iMac, and it ended up being a corrupt file. In the process, it happened to somehow overwrite the boot loader on my Mac. So, when I try to start up the boot loader menu by holding down option on power-on, it no longer appears with my HDD and guest account. It's literally just a question mark. Now, Apple's OS's are only available on the App Store, making it near impossible to download the OS X dmg and reinstall it. Does anyone have any reccomendations?

Comment: What version of OS X were you using?

Comment: What model of iMac is more important than what OS it was running - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not interested in recovering your data, you can restore your Mac to working order by booting to Internet Recovery.  Hold down <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> during the boot process and it will connect to Apple's servers and allow you to do a factory restore of your Mac (provided it is a 2011 model or newer).

You always have to use caution when installing Linux on a Mac.  By default, Apple uses a CoreStorage partition for the operating system, and a regular HFS+ partition (with a non-standard GUID) for the recovery partition.  CoreStorage is a proprietary Apple partition type to support their FileVault and FusionDrive technologies.

Linux does not understand CoreStorage volumes.  Additionally, if your Mac booted the Linux disc via the built-in BIOS compatibility module rather than native EFI (which many models do to support Windows via Boot Camp), then Linux probably didn't understand the drive's GPT format either.

What has likely happened is that Linux attempted to re-partition the hard drive during the setup process and destroyed the partition structure that was already there.  If that's the case, then there is little hope of getting your data back, and a factory restore is your best option.  Let's hope you have a good backup.